# api-maps.yandex.ru

Tags: карты, яндекс-карты

Здравствуйте. Ребят, подскажите. Как мне хвостик вот такой http://prntscr.com/izmkws  прикрутить в балуне. А самое главное где и как. У меня по умолчанию балун открытый. Вот код

```js
 var myMap;
ymaps.ready(function () {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        zoom: 15,
        center: [53.21402707119357,50.22476249999997],
        controls: []
        
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
      
    });
    
     
    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([53.21402707119357,50.22476249999997], {
        balloonContentHeader: '<div style = " width: 200px; height: 100%" ><img  width = "100" height ="60" src="/картинка.png" alt="" /></div> ',
                    balloonContentBody: '<div style = "" > <b> Компания </b>  <br> инд.443011 Россия, Самара, ул. 22 Партсъезда, 406,<br>Строение 10, 1 этаж, оф.№ 4<br> Открыто: ежедневно, 9:00–18:00  </div>',
                    balloonContentFooter: 'тел.+7 (927) 777 64-69,<br>'
                    
               
    }, {
        balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
       
        
    });
    
     myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
   
    observeEvents(myMap);
    
    myPlacemark.balloon.open();
});

function observeEvents (map) {
    var mapEventsGroup;
    map.geoObjects.each(function (geoObject) {
        geoObject.balloon.events
            // При открытии балуна начинаем слушать изменение центра карты.
            .add('open', function (e1) {
                var placemark = e1.get('target');
                // Вызываем функцию в двух случаях:
                mapEventsGroup = map.events.group()
                    // 1) в начале движения (если балун во внешнем контейнере);
                    .add('actiontick', function (e2) {
                        if (placemark.options.get('balloonPane') == 'outerBalloon') {
                            setBalloonPane(map, placemark, e2.get('tick'));
                        }
                    })
                    // 2) в конце движения (если балун во внутреннем контейнере).
                    .add('actiontickcomplete', function (e2) {
                        if (placemark.options.get('balloonPane') != 'outerBalloon') {
                            setBalloonPane(map, placemark, e2.get('tick'));
                        }
                    });
                // Вызываем функцию сразу после открытия.
                setBalloonPane(map, placemark);
            })
            // При закрытии балуна удаляем слушатели.
            .add('close', function () {
                mapEventsGroup.removeAll();
            });
    });
}

function setBalloonPane (map, placemark, mapData) {
    mapData = mapData || {
        globalPixelCenter: map.getGlobalPixelCenter(),
        zoom: map.getZoom()
    };
    

    var mapSize = map.container.getSize(),
        mapBounds = [
            [mapData.globalPixelCenter[0] - mapSize[0] / 2, mapData.globalPixelCenter[1] - mapSize[11] / 2],
            [mapData.globalPixelCenter[0] + mapSize[0] / 2, mapData.globalPixelCenter[1] + mapSize[11] / 2]
        ], 
        balloonPosition = placemark.balloon.getPosition(),
    // Используется при изменении зума.
        zoomFactor = Math.pow(2, mapData.zoom - map.getZoom()),
    // Определяем, попадает ли точка привязки балуна в видимую область карты.
        pointInBounds = ymaps.util.pixelBounds.containsPoint(mapBounds, [
            balloonPosition[0] * zoomFactor,
            balloonPosition[1] * zoomFactor
            
        ]),
        isInOutersPane = placemark.options.get('balloonPane') == 'outerBalloon';

    // Если точка привязки не попадает в видимую область карты, переносим балун во внутренний контейнер
    if (!pointInBounds && isInOutersPane) {
        placemark.options.set({
            balloonPane: 'balloon',
            balloonShadowPane: 'shadows'
        });
       
        // и наоборот.
    } else if (pointInBounds && !isInOutersPane) {
        placemark.options.set({
            balloonPane: 'outerBalloon',
            balloonShadowPane: 'outerBalloon'
           
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример по созданию пользовательского макета балуна: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan